# Change placeholder when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking to add a placeholder to a textbox when the browser has a smaller width than 800 and im not sure where im going wrong.

```
<form class="info">
            <script>add();</script>
            <label>Name</label> <input type="text" class="box" name="name" placeholder="" size="40"><br><br>
</form>
```

And the JS

```
<script>
function add(){ 
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
if (w < 800) {
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].placeholder='Name';
} else
{
}}
</script>
```

Comment: You run your function before the input exists in the DOM so you will get an "Uncaught TypeError". Move the `<script>` after the `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  if (w < 800) {
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].placeholder='Name';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].placeholder='';
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrLMgm?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what i wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

In your above code you defined a function that will execute some javascript when called.

But where are you calling your add function?  You should be doing it on the window resize event, if you want it executed each time the browser window is resized.

Example:

```
<script>
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w < 800) {
           document.getElementsByName('name')[0].placeholder='Name';
        } else {
           document.getElementsByName('name')[0].placeholder='';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah i realized i was calling it incorrectly, both your answers work the way i intended to implement it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In case you hadn't considered it, you can use CSS media queries to simply hide the placeholder text on larger browsers, without doing anything with JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<form class="info">
<label>Name</label> 
<input type="text" class="box" name="name" placeholder="Name" size="40">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input::placeholder {color:transparent;}
@media (max-width:800px) {
    input::placeholder {color:gray;}
}
```

note: the CSS should have the proper vendor-prefixes for placeholder, which I did not add in just for simplicity here.  please see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: Interesting, i used css to remove the label, @media screen and (max-width:800px){label{ display: none;}} but didnt consider using it for the placeholder. Thanks